# Bug debido a que no se ha iniciado sesión

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo 2 tablas:
User:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('saldo');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Y la otra Entrada:

```
Schema::create('entradas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('usuario');
            $table->foreign('usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('cantidad');
            $table->string('tipo');
            $table->date('fecha');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Estas tablas tienen una relación foranea por la que cada usuario puede tener varias entradas, pero cada entrada es de un solo usuario:

User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'saldo', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function entra(){
        return $this->hasMany(Entrada::class,'usuario');
    }
}
```

Entrada.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Entrada extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
        'usuario', 'cantidad', 'tipo', 'fecha',
    ];

    public function comprador(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'usuario');
    }
}
```

Y aqui tenemos la vista en la que se mostrara la lista de entradas del usuario actualmente conectado:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
@Logged()
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Tus entradas") }} </h1>

    @forelse($ticket as $t)
    <div class="panel-body">
    -{{ $t->cantidad }} entradas de tipo {{ $t->tipo }}
    </div>
    @empty
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ __("No has comprado ninguna entrada por ahora") }}
    </div>
    @endforelse
    <div>
        @if(Auth::user()->saldo>=5)
        <p><a href="./compra">Comprar una entrada</a></p>
        @endif
        <p> Saldo: {{Auth::user()->saldo}} </p>
        <p><a href="./ingreso">Realizar un ingreso</a></p>
    </div>
@else
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Para poder ver tus entradas tendras que iniciar sesión") }} </h1>
@endLogged
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Y aqui, la función del controlador:

```
public function index(){
        $ticket=Auth::user()->entra()->with(['comprador'])->paginate(5);
        return view('animal.index', compact('ticket'));
    }
```

Este codigo normalmente funciona, pero si no se ha iniciado sesión da error.
¿Como lo arreglo?

Aclaro ademas una cosa: En caso de que el usuario aun no se haya conectado, en lugar de la lista de tickets mostrara un mensaje solicitando que inicie sesión.

Comment: ¿qué error muestra?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para que alguien te ayude. El código no funciona porque cuando no estás logueado la funcion de Auth::user() no va obtener nada. ¿Qué se supone que debe hacer tu código?

Comment: @PAGANA en caso de que no este conectado, debe simplemente mostrar un mensaje solicitando que inicie sesión para ver su lista de tickets.

Comment: No entiendo porque un usuario que no se ha loguedo puede entrar a esa página donde muestras información de una cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno puedes hacer lo siguiente: cambia tu controladora y dejala tal y cual te lo muestro akí.

```
public function index(){
    $ticket= (Auth::guest()) ? [] : Auth::user()->entra()->with(['comprador'])->paginate(5);
    return view('animal.index', compact('ticket'));
}
```

Con esto solo devuelves los resultados cuando el usuario está logueado sino será un arreglo vacío.

Y en tu vista cambia @Loggued por @auth lo mismo para sus cierres @endLoggued por @endAuth, funciona en Laravel 5.5 y 5.6 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade). Y para añadirle el mensaje de que debe loguearse usa lo siguiente:

```
@guest
    <h2>Debe iniciar sessión, para ver esta página,
    haga click <a href="{{ route('auth_login') }}">aquí</a> para entrar.</h2>
@endguest
```

Es auth_login si deseas ir hacia la página de inicio de sessión y por supuesto,
esta se llama así, sino es el nombre que le hayas dado en tus rutas.

Comment: Ahora consigo que no haya error si no he iniciado sesión, pero cuando la inicio me encuentro este mensaje de error: View [targeta] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\animalada\resources\views\animal\index.blade.php)